# add firebase object ID to routerlink attribute in Angular

Tags: javascript, html, angular

So I'm working on a website with Angular and Firebase database about Playstation games . Every game that I want to display has an ID that I want to pass to the routerlink attribute. I just don't know how to do this. I tried the code below (routerLink=["/games", {{game.key$}}]), but it gives me the shown error. Can someone help me?

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let game of games; let i = index">
      <div class="col-4">
        <div class="card">
          <img class="card-img-top" src="{{ game.imageUrl }}" alt="hello">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h4 class="card-title">{{ game.title }}</h4>
            <p class="card-text">{{ game.category }}</p>
          </div>
          <div class="card-footer">
            <button
              routerLink=["/games", {{game.key$}}]
              class="btn btn-secondary btn-block">Available Tournaments
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div *ngIf="(i+1)%3 === 0" class="w-100"></div>
      </ng-container>
```

> compiler.js:485 Uncaught Error: Template parse errors: Unexpected
>   closing tag "button". It may happen when the tag has already been
>   closed by another tag. For more info see
>   https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#closing-elements-that-have-implied-end-tags (" {{game.key$}}]
>                 class="btn btn-secondary btn-block">Available Tournaments
>               [ERROR ->]

[image: structure of the database]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
<button [routerLink]="['/games', game.$key]" class="btn btn-secondary btn-block">Available Tournaments
</button>
```

Comment: Perfect! i just had to delete the ')' after the routerlink attribute and then it worked perfectly. Thank you so much.